# Change css style by classname using styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

In my project, I am using styled Component and installed react-responsive-carousel . As carousel is too big ,I want to add max-height property in classname=carousel.

I tried this but it didn't worked.

```
    const Wrapper = styled.div`
       &.carousel {
        max-height: 450px;
    }
`

    <Wrapper>
      <Carousel showThumbs={false} infiniteLoop={true} autoPlay>
       ................
      </Carousel>
    </Wrapper>
```

[image]

How can I do that or if there is an easy way to customize. please let me know

Comment: When you say it didn't work are you saying you see your rule in the computed styled panel in the dev tools but that it didn't override anything in the `.carousel` class? Can you show more of those computed styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey so, you are using the wrong css selector.

This code here is trying going to apply the styles to the div `Wrapper` that also has a class of `carousel`

```
   const Wrapper = styled.div`
       &.carousel {
        max-height: 450px;
    }`

    <Wrapper>
      <Carousel showThumbs={false} infiniteLoop={true} autoPlay>
       ................
      </Carousel>
    </Wrapper>
```

You can do 2 things, either select the class `carousel` inside the Wrapper and then use both the `Wrapper` and the `Carousel` components as you are using, like this.

```
   const Wrapper = styled.div`
       .carousel {
        max-height: 450px;
    }`

    <Wrapper>
      <Carousel showThumbs={false} infiniteLoop={true} autoPlay>
       ................
      </Carousel>
    </Wrapper>
```

Or you can extend the styles from `Carousel` without creating a `Wrapper`, like this.

```
   const ExtendedCarousel = styled(Carousel)`
        max-height: 450px;
    `

      <ExtendedCarousel showThumbs={false} infiniteLoop={true} autoPlay>
       ................
      </ExtendedCarousel>
```